# Color changes of the buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm new to this programming. I would like to build an application for windows. The easiest way to this app was to put some buttons (55 yet) to the main window.xaml. I would like to program one of the buttons. It is called " U ". When the people press the U button (not on the keyboard) the app would change the colors of the button. I started to make a program. First for all I putted the U button onto the main window, renamed it like the other ones. After that I double clicked on it, so I was able to edit the function in the main window.xaml.cs. I wrote this program:

```
P1.Background = K1.Background ; // (red - - > blue) 
K1.Background = N1.Background ; // (blue  - - > orange)  
N1.Background = Z1.Background ; // (orange  - - > green) 
Z1.Background = P1.Background ; // (green - - > red)
```

The background colors already set to the P1, K1, N1, Z1 buttons right after I created them.

My problem is that when I press the U button, the program runs correctly, and the last swap (Z1 = P1) fails, because earlier I set the P1 color to the K1 color, that's why the Z1 actually K1. (I can see two blue buttons and no red). The way to set the Z1 color to red not good, because P1 and Z1  could be any other color. Other way to first swap the Z1 to P1 then on the last N1 to Z1 isn't good, I will not have green. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, save the color of `P1` to a temporary variable at first.

```
var tempP1 = P1.Background;
P1.Background = K1.Background ; // (red - - > blue) 
K1.Background = N1.Background ; // (blue  - - > orange)  
N1.Background = Z1.Background ; // (orange  - - > green) 
Z1.Background = tempP1 ; // (green - - > red)
```